# Deserializing multiple objects in json string

Tags: json, vb.net

I am consuming a web service that is sending multiple objects in a json string.

```
{  "id": null,  "method": "ready",  "params": [    {      "accept": 1,      "serial": "001d50101979"    },
{
  "result": {
    "serial": "001d50101979",
    "name": "001d50101979",
    "model": "HMP200",
    "mode": "normal",
    "firmware": {
      "version": "3.2.2-1.0.28801",
      "status": "normal"
    },
    "uptime": "233.50",
    "bootid": "e62f7839-95b1-4775-8476-c0b1b5b4857f"
  },
  "error": null,
  "id": 1231
}  ] }
```

I am using the following classes

```
Public Class Firmware
   Public Property version As String
   Public Property status As String
End Class
Public Class Result
   Public Property serial As String
   Public Property name As String
   Public Property model As String
   Public Property mode As String
   Public Property firmware As Firmware
   Public Property uptime As String
   Public Property bootid As String
End Class
Public Class Param
   Public Property accept As Integer
   Public Property serial As String
End Class
Public Class Player
   Public Property id As Object
   Public Property method As String
   Public Property params As Param()
End Class
```

I have no issue deserializing the root class `Player` but I am not sure how to deserialize the class Result.

```
 Dim Player As New Player
 Player = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Player)(JsonString)
 Dim FirmwareVersion As String = Player.id
 Dim bootid As String = Player.method
 Dim Model As String = Player.params(0).accept
 Dim Serial As String = Player.params.ElementAt(0).serial
```

Comment: The `Param` class is wrong.  It should contain `Result`.  Run your json through something like json2csharp.

Comment: Param and result are being passed as two separate separate classes. The Param class is included in the Player class and I can access it. The Result class is not included in the Player classes and I am not sure how to access it.

Comment: When I run the json though a json to C#  I get the following classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your class `Param` to

```
Public Class Param
    Public Property accept As Integer
    Public Property serial As String
    Public Property result As Result
End Class
```

then you can access your `result` like so

```
Dim Player As New Player
Player = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Player)(JsonString)
Dim FirmwareVersion As String = Player.id
Dim bootid As String = Player.method
Dim Model As String = Player.params(0).accept
Dim Serial As String = Player.params.ElementAt(0).serial

For Each p In Player.params
    If p.result IsNot Nothing Then
        Console.WriteLine(p.result.model)
    End If
Next
```